# Excuse me for asking, but how many are running Powershell V3

Tags: powershell

I know this isn't a programming question but I would really like the users of this sites opinion on the subject.

How many of you are running Ps3 and have you made a conplete switch or are you still developing Ps2 scripts?

Thinking about making the leap myself and would really like some input.

Comment: Well, I'd consider PowerShell a programmers tool. (And I did not know there was a v3)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a forum for opinion questions. Feel free to ask questions about programming, though.

Comment: Best place for asking this question - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running V3 just to check out what's coming, and to get the Intellisense and new ISE for writing scripts.

I don't have it deployed to any of my servers, and I test all the scripts I write under V2 before I run them there.  All you have to do is run

```
powershell -version 2
```

from a console prompt and your in a nested runspace in a V2 environment and can run your your script there to check it for compatibility.

Comment: Keep in mind that there are some issues with invoking -version 2 when running V3.  IIRC jobs invoked this way actually uses V3 and there are some issues with help (either not there or listing parameters that only exists in V3).

Comment: Thanks.  I've seen the issues with Help.  Didn't realize the background jobs used a V3 runspace, but I can see how it might do that.

Comment: Help totally does not work for me using Ps3 in Win8 CP.

Comment: http://richardspowershellblog.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/powershell-v3-updateable-help/

Comment: Yep, the team chose not to ship help in the box which will allow them to update help much more frequently than service packs or a new Windows release.  The downside of course is that the Get-Help experience is limited to what PowerShell can discover via Reflection *until* you execute Update-Help.  Hopefully the team can modify Get-Help to notify users that they initially need to run Update-Help to enhance the help content.

Comment: @KeithHill What? You have to have an internet connection? No good for  systems on secure networks! Sure there are some issues with it here and there but at least its something! They could make local help updates available like IE compatibly mode updates or root CA updates. Silly :-(

Comment: @AndyArismendi - There's a Save-Help command that can be used on a machine that does have a network connection.  Then you can point Update-Help to that path - say on a USB thumb drive.  Not ideal I know and believe me, the MVPs made sure the team knew about the various issues associated with shipping no help on the box.

Comment: @KeithHill Grrr typically there is no access to the internet anywhere on such networks (or even premises) and getting data into such locations via sneaknet is not a simple process

Answer (score 1):

I'm running it on all my dev machines. :-)